# Prove by induction that $\frac{d^m }{dx^m}\Bigl(\frac{d^nf}{dx^n}\Bigl)=\frac{d^{m+n}f}{dx^{m+n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have to prove by induction that :

> *$\frac{d^m }{dx^m}\Bigl(\frac{d^nf}{dx^n}\Bigl)=\frac{d^{m+n}f}{dx^{m+n}}$*      where $m,n  
> \in \mathbb{N}$

What I tried:

1. For $m=1$ the formula is true :

Starting from this one:

$f^{(n)}(x)=\Bigl(f^{(n-1)}(x)\Bigl)'$ or $\frac{d^{n}f}{dx^{n}}=\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(\frac{d^{n-1}f}{dx^{n-1}}\Bigl)$ $...(*)$

I can prove that for $m=1$ it holds from the definition that:

$\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(\frac{d^{n}f}{dx^{n}}\Bigl)=\frac{d^{n+1}f}{dx^{n+1}}$

2.Now I suppose that the formula above holds for some $m>1 \in \mathbb{N}$

> $\frac{d^{m}}{dx^{m}}\Bigl(\frac{d^{n}f}{dx^{n}}\Bigl)=\frac{d^{n+m}f}{dx^{n+m}}$ $...(**)$ Inductive Hypothesis

3.Then I prove that it holds for $m+1 \in \mathbb{N}$ too:

$\frac{d^{m+1}}{dx^{m+1}}\Bigl(\frac{d^nf}{dx^{n}}\Bigl)=(*)=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{d^{m}}{dx^{m}}\Bigl(\frac{d^{n}f}{dx^{n}}\Bigl)\bigg)=(**)=\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(\frac{d^{n+m}f}{dx^{n+m}}\Bigl)=(*)=\frac{d^{n+m+1}f}{dx^{n+m+1}}$

My first question is : Is this proof correct?

And my second question is about this formula : $f^{(n)}(x)=\Bigl(f^{(n-1)}(x)\Bigl)'$ or $\frac{d^{n}f}{dx^{n}}=\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(\frac{d^{n-1}f}{dx^{n-1}}\Bigl)$ , I understand the first one $f^{(n)}(x)=\Bigl(f^{(n-1)}(x)\Bigl)'$  comes by definition of the $n$th derivative,  but in the second one it uses differentials, and I know that it is also based on definition but I don't clearly understand how it works with differentials. Anyone who could answer my questions will be highly appreciated .Thank you!

Comment: I don't think your proof is right. I think you are defining $D^{n+1}=D D^{n}$, which is OK; but then you use without comment/proof that $D^{m+1}=D^{m}D$ which hasn't been proved--indeed it is an unproved case of the theorem you're trying to prove.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Can you tell me in which part did I use that ?

Comment: At the very first equality in 3.

Comment: @ancientmathematician is it now correct?

Comment: I tried to write down a clean proof, using fixed $n$ and induction over $m$ but it seemed fishy. The basic property to prove seems the associativity of the derivative to me and induction not needed except for the inductive definition of a higher derivative.

Comment: @mvw I don't really understand what do you mean by "the associativity of the derivative" !

Comment: @mvw but why do I need it, I proved the formula without using this property.

Comment: No, you use it several times in your step 3.

Comment: @mvw No, on the step 3 I only used step 2 and step 1 and this property : $\frac{df}{dx}=f′ dx$ nothing else.

Comment: @mvw by the step 1 just here we have $m$ instead of $n$, and in the first step function was just $f$, and here the function is $\frac{d^{n}f}{dx^{n}}$. Everything else is the same . So I based on the step 1 not on that "associativity property"

Comment: I believe the version you have now written, the inductive step is right. I'd prefer it if (a) you  missed out the step where you mix the notations and (importantly (b) for each equality you gave a reason, such as "definition of $D^{m+1}(D^{n} f)$", "inductive hypothesis", "definition of $D^{(m+n)+1}f$".

Comment: @ancientmathematician Okay I'll try to give a reason of each step now, and about the first one (a) can you tell me where did I mix the notations please, thank you!

Comment: Either do it all as $d/dx$ or all in $f'$. Omit the one with the dash.

Comment: @ancientmathematician is it now correct

Comment: I like reasons!

Comment: @ancientmathematician I added reasons now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write $Df$ for $\frac{df}{dx}$.

We have to be absolutely clear what we mean by $D^{n}\phi$ where $n$ is a natural number for any function $\phi$.  We define this recursively: 
$$ D^{0}\phi:=\phi; \ \ \ D^{n+1}\phi:=D D^{n}\phi.$$

We are asked to prove for all natural numbers that $D^{m}(D^{n}f)=D^{m+n}f$.

Fix $n$ and proceed by induction.

**Root case**, $m=0$.

$D^{0} D^{n}f=D^{n}f$ by the definition of $D^{0}$. And $D^{n}f=D^{0+n}f$ by the usual properties of addition of natural numbers.

**Inductive step**. Assume $D^{m} D^{n}f=D^{m+n}f$ and prove that $D^{m+1}D^{n}f=D^{m+n+1}f$

(a) Now $D^{m+1}D^{n}f=D (D^{m} D^{n} f)$ by the definition of $D^{m+1}(D^{n}f)$.

(b) By the inductive hypothesis, $D^{m} D^{n} f=D^{m+n}f$, so we have 
$D^{m+1}D^{n}f=D (D^{m+n} f)$.

(c) By the definition of $D^{m+n+1}f$ we have that $D D^{m+n}f =D^{m+n+1}f$.

Putting these together we have that $D^{m+1}D^{n}f=D^{m+n+1}f$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof of $$\frac{d^m }{dx^m}\Bigl(\frac{d^nf}{dx^n}\Bigl)=\frac{d^{m+n}f}{dx^{m+n}}$$

using mathematical induction is flawless.

On your question about $$f^{(n)}(x)=\Bigl(f^{(n-1)}(x)\Bigl)'$$

in comparison with $$\frac{d^{n}f}{dx^{n}}=\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(\frac{d^{n-1}f}{dx^{n-1}}\Bigl)$$
They are the same thing.

You may use one or the other as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About the second question I know that they are the same but I want to know how to kinda "convert" them?

Comment: d/dx is a symbol and  it is used for the first derivative. so y' is the same as dy/dx. The advantage of dy/dx over y' is that  it shows the independent variable x as well. Now d/dx(dy/dx) is simply written as d^2y/dx^2  and it means y'', and so forth.

Comment: Okay I'll try to understand it thank you. Now I don't understand if my proof is correct or not, cause someone said in comment above that it is not right?

Comment: @MathsSurvivor Ask them what is wrong.